# MySQL query optimization, VERY SLOW

Tags: mysql

This is what I would like to achieve:

Show 50 last students and their cheapest products.

If product doesn't exist present empty values.

Here is the SELECT query:

```
SELECT 
students.*,
cs.cheapest_id,
cs.cheapest_price
FROM students
LEFT JOIN (SELECT iqs.* FROM (
        SELECT 
        student_id,
        id AS cheapest_id,
        price AS cheapest_price
        FROM products
        ORDER BY price ASC
) AS iqs
GROUP BY iqs.student_id) AS cs ON cs.student_id = students.id
ORDER BY students.name DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `students` VALUES ('1', 'Mark');
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES ('2', 'Chris');

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('1', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('2', '1', '3');
```

Result:

```
id  name    cheapest_id cheapest_price
1   Mark    1           2
2   Chris   (NULL)      (NULL)
```

Here is the problem:

If there are many records in both tables query is very slow(minutes).

If I use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN or if I remove "ORDER BY students.name DESC" query is fast.

I have set index on student_id but still it is very slow.

Can anyone please help? I've been struggling with this for days...

Edit: The result of EXPLAIN

```
1   PRIMARY students    ALL 3   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL 2   
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL 4   Using temporary; Using filesort 
3   DERIVED products    ALL 4   Using filesort
```

Comment: 1 PRIMARY students ALL     3 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY <derived2> ALL     2 
2 DERIVED <derived3> ALL     4 Using temporary; Using filesort
3 DERIVED products ALL     4 Using filesort

Comment: I have ORDER BY before grouping because I can't group and order in same query. ORDER BY must happen before GROUP BY.

Comment: Nevermind, I always forget that MySQL is liberal compared to ansi or other dmbs when it comes to group by

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `students` ADD INDEX (`id`, `name`);
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD INDEX (`student_id`, `id`, `price`);
```

and write your query like this:

```
SELECT students.*,
   MIN(products.id) AS cheapest_id,
   MIN(products.price) AS cheapest_price

FROM students
LEFT JOIN products ON student_id = students.id

GROUP BY students.id
ORDER BY students.name DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

You should definately read about the EXPLAIN SELECT syntax and how to index properly: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

With **EXPLAIN SELET %YOUR QUERY%** you can see how MySQL is optimizing the query and how the engine is actually reading your datasets.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, I already checked EXPLAIN multiple times but still I can't find solution for this. Your SELECT query is also wrong as it gets smallest product id and not the id of cheapest product. This part is wrong -  MIN(products.id) AS cheapest_id.

Comment: And if you use your query but with my suggested indexes?

Comment: Yes, I had those indexes on original tables already with 100 thousand+ records but it still doesn't work. Only thing I didn't have index on id as they are primary keys already.

Comment: You definitely need proper indexing as well as an optimized query. I don't see those indexes in your example table. How many examined rows do you have shown in your explain select?

Comment: I have added indexes on everything now as you suggested but it still slow. Here is screenshot of explain: http://i.imgur.com/Z9OwAuv.png. And I am still using my query.

Comment: That cannot be, it should say "Using index" and showing the correct index under "ref" column. Are you sure you added the combined indexes exactly like i did? Can you post a "SHOW CREATE TABLE" result of students and products?